# is training dataset of machine learning are Big Data processing results?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, large-data, train

I need to understand the application of machine learning in big data processing. I am so confused with the concept of big data processing and machine learning and I need clear responses. In general, machine learning requires big data for model training. Training need a dataset which is versioned and managed of features and labels. For example, we have raw data collected from social media and stored in the Cloud.  These data needs to be cleaned. Then, features selection and extraction process is needed to generate the training dataset. If we talk about big data processing, big data are processed using for example Hadoop. So, what is the relation between this process and machine learning feature extraction and selection? Is dataset training represents the big data processing result or feature extraction and selection are performed on a precessed big data?